# Modifying JS pager - how to substitute html elements using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Here is the initial code:

```
<div class="fs-table-table">
    <div class="fs-table-row header">
        <div class="fs-table-cell">
        Course Name
        </div>
        <div class="fs-table-cell">
        Lessons
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fs-table-content">

    </div>
</div>
```

Now the pager file calls:

```
$('#' + options.contentHolder).html(template(pager, options.template, options.currentData, options.startPage, options.perPage, options.alwaysShowPager, options.informationToShow, options.errorTemplate));
```

where contentHolder is 'fs-table-content', and it points to a template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="weeklyLessonTemplate">

    <div class="fs-table-row">
        <div class="fs-table-cell" data-title="Course Name">

            ##courseName##

        </div>
        <div class="fs-table-cell" data-title="Lesson">
            <input type="radio" class="radio" name="weekly_lesson" value="##lessons##" />
            <label for="##lessons##">##lessons##
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

</script>
```

and it yields:

```
<div class="fs-table-table">
    <div class="fs-table-row header">
        <div class="fs-table-cell">
        Course Name
        </div>
        <div class="fs-table-cell">
        Lessons
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="fs-table-row">
        <div class="fs-table-cell" data-title="Course Name">

            Art/Music/Social Media

        </div>
        <div class="fs-table-cell" data-title="Lesson">
            <input type="radio" class="radio" name="weekly_lesson" value="What is art?">
            <label for="What is art?">What is art?
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

So you see, calling the function "template" simply returns html code.  Now, when I click on the next page number, I expect the html to change but it doesn't change, it stays the same because

```
<div id="fs-table-content">

</div>
```

has been replaced.  How do I inject fs-table-content back into the code.  It should be put in the page onclick code:

```
$('#' + pager).on('click', '.page, .last-page, .first-page, .next-pages, .prev-pages', function(e) {
        var newPage = parseInt($(this).data('value'));
        var perPage = parseInt($('#' + pager + ' .perPage').val());
        $('#' + pager + ' .page.current').removeClass('current');
        $('#' + pager + ' .page[data-value="' + newPage + '"]').addClass('current');

        showProperPaging(pager, newPage, options.totalPages, options.pagesToShow);

        $('#' + options.contentHolder).html(template(pager, options.template, options.currentData, newPage, perPage, options.alwaysShowPager, options.informationToShow, options.errorTemplate));
        options.currentPage = newPage;

        $('#' + pager).trigger("pagingChange");
});
```

I noticed that in the demo for the pager, they use the following line to change the html:

```
var showing = $('#' + templateToShow).html().format(data);
html += showing;
```

But my data is structured differently, I don't think I can use .format

Comment: The original pager site is here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Dynamic-Pagination-Plugin-jQuery-simplePaging.html

Comment: I am pretty dumb.  I forgot I removed the wrapper when I was doing my initial tests on the code.

Comment: This was the code that was the cause of my misery:
$('#fs-table-content').contents().unwrap();

Answer (score 0):

The way this script has been designed is that you need to provide two separate divs (not nested within one another). One for your content and one of its content (where it places pagination, search .. etc).

So you can change your code to this for it work:

```js
!function(a){function e(e,t,r,n,o,s,g){var p="",l=Math.ceil(t/r);p+='<div class="showing"></div>',p+='<div class="pager"><span class="first-page btn" data-value="1">First</span><span class="prev-page btn">Previous</span><span class="prev-pages btn" data-value="1">...</span><span class="page btn current" data-value="1">1</span>';for(var i=1;i<l;i++)p+='<span class="page btn" data-value="'+(i+1)+'">'+(i+1)+"</span>";p+='\t<span class="next-pages btn" data-value="6">...</span><span class="next-page btn">Next</span><span class="last-page btn" data-value="'+l+'">Last</span></div>',p+='<div class="options" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px;"><span>Show </span><select class="perPage">';for(i=0;i<n.length;i++)n[i]==r?p+='<option selected="selected">'+n[i]+"</option>":p+="<option>"+n[i]+"</option>";p+="\t</select><span> per page</span></div>",s&&(p+='<div class="searchBox"><input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search" value="'+g+'" /></div>'),a("#"+e).html(p)}function t(e,t,r,n){1==t?a("#"+e).find(".prev-page").hide():a("#"+e).find(".prev-page").show(),t==r?a("#"+e).find(".next-page").hide():a("#"+e).find(".next-page").show();var o,s,g=n,p=Math.ceil(g/2),l=Math.floor(g/2);r<g?(o=0,s=r):t>=1&&t<=p?(o=0,s=g):t+l>=r?(o=r-g,s=r):(o=t-p,s=t+l),a("#"+e+" .pager").children().each(function(){a(this).hasClass("page")&&a(this).hide()});for(var i=o;i<s;i++)o>0?(a("#"+e+" .prev-pages").show(),a("#"+e+" .prev-pages").data("value",o)):a("#"+e+" .prev-pages").hide(),a("#"+e+" .page[data-value='"+(i+1)+"']").show(),s<r?(a("#"+e+" .next-pages").show(),a("#"+e+" .next-pages").data("value",s+1)):a("#"+e+" .next-pages").hide();1==r?a("#"+e+" .last-page, #"+e+" .first-page").hide():0==r?a("#"+e+" .pager, #"+e+" .showing, #"+e+" .options").hide():(a("#"+e+" .pager, #"+e+" .showing, #"+e+" .options").show(),a("#"+e+" .last-page, #"+e+" .first-page").show())}function r(e,t,r,n,o,s,g,p){var l="",i=n*o-(o-1),h=n*o>r.length?r.length:n*o;if(r.length<=0){if(""==p)l+='<div class="dataError">There is nothing to show here.</div>';else l+=a("#"+p).html().format(["There are no Messages to display."]);return s||a("#"+e).hide(),l}a("#"+e).show(),a("#"+e+" .showing").html("Showing "+i+" to "+h+" of "+r.length+" total.");for(var c=n*o-o;c<n*o&&c!=r.length;c++){var u=[];a.each(g,function(a,e){u.push(r[c][e])}),l+=a("#"+t).html().format(u)}return l}a.fn.extend({paging:function(n){var o={data:{},contentHolder:"",template:"",errorTemplate:"",informationToShow:[],informationToRefineBy:[],perPage:10,pageLengths:[5,10,20,30,40,50],startPage:1,pagesToShow:5,showOptions:!0,showSearch:!0,alwaysShowPager:!0},s={currentPage:o.startPage,totalPages:0,currentData:n.data,refine:""};n=a.extend(o,n),(n=a.extend(s,n)).totalPages=Math.ceil(n.currentData.length/n.perPage),function(n,o){o.totalPages;e(n,o.currentData.length,o.perPage,o.pageLengths,o.showOptions,o.showSearch,o.refine),t(n,o.startPage,o.totalPages,o.pagesToShow),a("#"+o.contentHolder).html(r(n,o.template,o.currentData,o.startPage,o.perPage,o.alwaysShowPager,o.informationToShow,o.errorTemplate)),a("#"+n).on("click",".page, .last-page, .first-page, .next-pages, .prev-pages",function(e){var s=parseInt(a(this).data("value")),g=parseInt(a("#"+n+" .perPage").val());a("#"+n+" .page.current").removeClass("current"),a("#"+n+' .page[data-value="'+s+'"]').addClass("current"),t(n,s,o.totalPages,o.pagesToShow),a("#"+o.contentHolder).html(r(n,o.template,o.currentData,s,g,o.alwaysShowPager,o.informationToShow,o.errorTemplate)),o.currentPage=s,a("#"+n).trigger("pagingChange")}),a("#"+n).on("click",".next-page",function(e){var s=o.currentPage+1,g=parseInt(a("#"+n+" .perPage").val());a("#"+n+" .page.current").removeClass("current"),a("#"+n+' .page[data-value="'+s+'"]').addClass("current"),t(n,s,o.totalPages,o.pagesToShow),a("#"+o.contentHolder).html(r(n,o.template,o.currentData,s,g,o.alwaysShowPager,o.informationToShow,o.errorTemplate)),o.currentPage=s,a("#"+n).trigger("pagingChange")}),a("#"+n).on("click",".prev-page",function(e){var s=o.currentPage-1,g=parseInt(a("#"+n+" .perPage").val());a("#"+n+" .page.current").removeClass("current"),a("#"+n+' .page[data-value="'+s+'"]').addClass("current"),t(n,s,o.totalPages,o.pagesToShow),a("#"+o.contentHolder).html(r(n,o.template,o.currentData,s,g,o.alwaysShowPager,o.informationToShow,o.errorTemplate)),o.currentPage=s,a("#"+n).trigger("pagingChange")}),a("#"+n).on("change",".perPage",function(s){var g=parseInt(a(this).val());e(n,o.data.length,g,o.pageLengths,o.showOptions,o.showSearch,o.refine),o.totalPages=Math.ceil(o.currentData.length/g),t(n,o.startPage,o.totalPages,o.pagesToShow),a("#"+o.contentHolder).html(r(n,o.template,o.currentData,o.startPage,g,o.alwaysShowPager,o.informationToShow,o.errorTemplate)),o.currentPage=o.startPage,a("#"+n).trigger("pagingChange")}),a("#"+n).on("keyup",".search",function(e){var s=parseInt(a("#"+n+" .perPage").val()),g=a(this).val();o.refine=g;var p=function(e,t,r){if(""==t)return;var n=t.toLowerCase();dataToKeep=[];for(var o=0;o<e.length;o++)a.each(r,function(a,t){if(null!=e[o][t]&&e[o][t].toLowerCase().indexOf(n)>=0)return dataToKeep.push(e[o]),!1});return dataToKeep}(o.data,g,o.informationToRefineBy);p||(p=o.data),o.currentData=p;var l=Math.ceil(o.currentData.length/s);o.totalPages=l,t(n,o.startPage,o.totalPages,o.pagesToShow),a("#"+o.contentHolder).html(r(n,o.template,o.currentData,o.startPage,s,o.alwaysShowPager,o.informationToShow,o.errorTemplate)),a("#"+n).trigger("pagingChange")}),a("#"+n).on("focusin",".search",function(){o.refineFocus=!0}),a("#"+n).on("focusout",".search",function(){o.refineFocus=!1})}(a(this).attr("id"),n)}})}(jQuery),String.prototype.format=function(){var a=arguments;return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g,function(e,t){return void 0!==a[0][t]?a[0][t]:e})};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith"
  }, {
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "lastname": "Doe"
  }, {
    "firstname": "James",
    "lastname": "Smith"
  }, {
    "firstname": "Amanda",
    "lastname": "Doe"
  }, {
    "firstname": "Billy",
    "lastname": "Joe"
  }];

  $('#fs-table-table').paging({
    data: data, //This is the data that is being used. It is using JSON data so you can pull from any source if you want.
    contentHolder: 'fs-table-content', //The id for the area where you want the data to be displayed.
    template: 'weeklyLessonTemplate', //The template that is being used to display the data.
    errorTemplate: 'contentErrorTemplate', //The error template that is being used (optional)
    informationToShow: ['firstname', 'lastname'], //The information that you want to show from the given data
    informationToRefineBy: ['firstname', 'lastname'], //The information that you want to search on from the given data
    perPage: 1, //Default number to show per page. (Since we have a small amount of data only show 1.)
    pageLengths: [1, 2, 3, 4], //Options for number of items per page.
    startPage: 1, //The default start page. (Better to leave as 1 but can be changed if desired).
    pagesToShow: 4, //Number of pages to show at the top. If you have 10 pages it will show [...] when going above or below the this number.
    showOptions: true, //Show the per page options.
    showSearch: true, //Show the search bar.
    alwaysShowPager: true //Show the pager even if there isn't any data. Should be true if showSearch is true otherwise there will be problems.
  });
});
```

```css
.pager span.current {
  border: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.dataError {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.searchBox {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.searchBox .search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.showing {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu { display: block; }

.pager span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #a6a6a8 1px solid;
  padding: 5px 14px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.pager span:hover { background-color: #ddd; }

.pager span.current:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

.pager {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fs-table-content"></div>

<div id="fs-table-table"></div>


<script type="text/template" id="weeklyLessonTemplate">
  <div class="fs-table-row header">
    <div class="fs-table-cell">
      Course Name
    </div>
    <div class="fs-table-cell">
      Lessons
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="fs-table-content">
    <div class="fs-table-row">
      <div class="fs-table-cell" data-title="Course Name">
        {0}
      </div>
      <div class="fs-table-cell" data-title="Lesson">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="weekly_lesson" value="{1}" />
        <label for="{1}">{1}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: At the very end of the simplePaging1.0 file, they added the following, which is the whole key to the problem:

Comment: String.prototype.format = function() {
  var args = arguments;
  return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
    return typeof args[0][number] != 'undefined'
      ? args[0][number]
      : match
    ;
  });
};